# how do I concat MR/MS to their full name based on the wether they are male or female in sql, what is the error here

Tags: mysql

```
select customer_id,
case
 when o.customer_gender = 'M' then upper(concat('MR. ',concat(customer_fname,customer_lname)) 
 else upper(concat('MS. ',concat(customer_fname,customer_lname))
end as Customer_Full_name
from online_customer o;
```

So I am concatenating(Mr./Ms.) with the first and the last name based on their gender , but I am getting a syntax error here.

Comment: you didn't close the UPPER( with a closing parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

No need of calling `concat` inside another `concat` :

```
select customer_id,
case
 when customer_gender = 'M' then upper(concat('MR. ', customer_fname, ' ', customer_lname))
 else upper(concat('MR. ', customer_fname, ' ', customer_lname))
end as Customer_Full_name
from online_customer;
```